# Confusing indentation issue

Tags: python-3.x, indentation

I'm using an API from [this GIT repository](https://github.com/on1arf/jds6600_python) to control a JDS6600 signal generator.

Now some of the commands work & some dont due I think to the unit I'm using being slightly different to the one used by the author of the API.

So to fix this I tried to see what data the device was sending back before an error is raised. I thought a simple `print(data)` would do it but I keep getting an indentation error, sorry screen shots but I think you get a better idea from a picture in this case.

First with the newly added `print(data)`, note little red cross on the left

[image]

Second without,

[image]

So how come I'm getting this error? No matter where I place that `print(data)` within the method I get an indentation error & the code falls over.

**EDIT:** The problem was fixed running [reindent](https://pypi.org/project/reindent/) on the offending file, which converts all the tabs to spaces. As pointed out by Tyberius in a comment below the file was a mix of tabs & spaces. It seems Spyder has a unique attitude to such cases.

Comment: Does the code crash if you use it? If not, then it's a problem with the linter of the editor you're using, and that is not something that we really can help you with.

Comment: The code crashes & raises an indentation error `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`, I used just spaces no tabs involved.

Comment: As the error says, your file is inconsistently uses tabs and spaces. The whole file has to consistently use the same one.

Comment: @HampusLarsson if I insert the `print()` with just tabs I get the error, if I use just spaces I get the error. The code runs fine as long as I dont add the `print()` statement

Comment: @DrBwts Somewhat more unusual, the other lines could all be using a mix of tabs and spaces. If every line was written as `<tab> code`, the indenting with just tabs or spaces would be inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an error highlighted by the IDE (lint error), not an actual python error (you would get it after running and seeing a traceback).
In general anything after `:` is expected to be in the next line and IDE is probably making that assumption.

The general style guide is defined by [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) and it covers compound statements. The way you're trying to use is generally considered within the "rather not" section.

So really it should be

```py
if a not in (0, 1):
    raise RuntimeError(a)
print(data)
```

If you would use something like [black autoformatter](https://github.com/psf/black) it would sort it out for you.

Comment: When I format as you have in your post the indentation error appears even without me adding a `print()` statement.

Comment: Then you should check if you are not mixing up tabs and spaces or having some paste issues. If you delete the whitespace in front and add your own - it should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The line will actually fail. For example, look below:

```
   if a in [0.5,0.4]:
       raise TypeError(a)
   print("what")
   File "<stdin>", line 3
   print("what")
       ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now, why does this happen?
answer is [mentioned here](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/errors.html). Basically, as you define the error in the previous line, the error gets caught in the print. For example, it is technically similar to the following:

```
>>> while True print('Hello world')
File "<stdin>", line 1
while True print('Hello world')
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So that is why, your print is raising the error instead of the previous line. Also, there is no meaning of printing after you raise the error, as it will never get executed as the error will halt the execution. So the solution will be to put the print statement before the raise.

Comment: The error is only raised if the `if` statement is true, also, It happens even if I put the `print()` before the `if` statement

Comment: It seems that its a private method we are using. Do you think the print has to do anything with that?